# Proper way to grant root privilege to a task in a Python GUI app under Wayland

Tags: python, root, gui, wayland, privileges

I'm developing a `Python 3` software, that will be both a CLI and a GUI app, primarily targeting Linux. Here are the needs of my program:

- A small part of my program, let's say only a single function, needs `root` privileges to execute a particular task. If that matters, it will be a file operation on `/etc/resolv.conf`.
- The software will have its CLI and GUI components separated.
- I certainly don't want to grant `root` privilege to whole application (this also concerns `wayland`, see below).
- The software should also be working on `wayland` display server protocol, as many distros are moving towards it, and it is safer.

Now my question is, what is the proper way in `Python` to ask for `sudo` or `root` password if the user wants to execute the task that requires `root` privileges in the software (in the context of `Wayland` as stated before)?

**Note:** Python specific answers would be perfect, but I'm open to general solutions as well, since it would give me a starting point. Because right now, I don't know what to search.

Comment: "I originally posted this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611959/proper-way-to-grant-root-privilege-to-a-task-in-a-python-gui-app-under-wayland) but since I did not get any replies, I thought it might be better to ask here." You're not supposed to do that.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica even if you realize that unix&linux community might be better suited? If that is the case I can delete this post?

Comment: If you think it's a better fit here, then you can keep this one and delete that one, but one of them has to go.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica thanks for pointing out, I deleted the one on stackoverflow.

Comment: @kmotoko Did you figure out a sensible way to do this.  The solution I'm pondering is a seperate setuid root script called by the original one, but I dislike the lack of granularity in this solution.